# Kendo jQuery version limitation hurts even more with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, visual-studio-2013, telerik-mvc

Using Visual Studio 2013 and MVC 5.  It create all new projects with jQuery version 2.  As a result Kendo UI Web will not work without reworking the project.  This is the product weakness that would eliminate Kendo in the product evaluation.  Is Telerik planning to better support such standard environments?  Is this designed in limitation true for for the ASP.Net MVC product?

Prior Telerik products kindly did work with current jQuery versions.

Comment: My crystal ball says _bzzzt_

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI works with jQuery 2.0.